# One exposed filter for many views/views blocks

Tags: views

I want to have one exposed filter and 2 blocks displaying different content types. They both have 'date' field and I want to show same-day content with one date exposed filter.

Anyone knows how to achieve this? Do I have to create one or two different views? How to share exposed filter (ie. field_content_type_1_date) with another content type (which has field_content_type_2_date field)?

Answer (score 0):

If the two content types are using the same date_field and the blocks are shown on the same url, you can use the exposed filter of one view display to filter both views blocks. You just have to configure the exposed filter on the same field in both views/displays

Comment: How two content types can share one field? Date type in my example?

Comment: you can use the field "field_date" (or whatever it is called) in both content types. Just add an existing field in your content type

Answer (score 0):

You need *Views Global Filter* module, it can be found here:

https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it shows date filter not the way I want to.